# Spring security showing error console when login fails, how do I stop that

Tags: angularjs, spring-security

I have inherited an AngularJS app that uses Spring Security to handle login.  I have a different app, and when a user tries to go to a non-authenticated page (i.e. reloading the app after their session has expired) it does the proper thing: it simple puts "login failed" on the login screen, and lets the user log in.

The appI inherited throws up two consecutive dialogs with html say "you failed", followed by an error console, and only when all that's been dismissed does the user get to log in.

How do I make it so none of those things ever show up, and the user's just taken to the login screen?

Comment: this is the kind of question that can't possibly be answered without a [mcve].

Comment: Really @Claies? There's no "this is what you do with Spring to get a dialog"?  There's no "set this in Spring and it will return a 401 with no text"?